# Colors in baked texture

Tags: shaders, color

I'm trying to bake a procedurally generated texture. Everything seems to work except the colors seem to be off from what I expect. To narrow things down, I've removed everything from my shader except an emit shader with an rgb color (255, 0, 0) and intensity 1. If I just render the object using cycles, the colors shows up as a red (255,0,0). However, when I bake this into a texture and save it to a file, the red colour is now (206,0,0).

I'm a bit lost as to where the problem could be! Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was the color management. Setting it to raw gave me what I expected.